# Email Campaign hits not showing up in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to set up a campaign for an email that would track when the email is being opened by clients. The URL I'm using is the following:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-xxxxxxxx-2&cid=3.3&t=event&ec=template3.3&ea=open&cn=template3.3&cm=email
```

Replaced numbers in `tid` with `xxxxxxxx` for security.

If I pass this URL through the google debugger it says a hit is recorded. In Google Analytics however, the events are showing up properly with `Event Category = template3.3` and `Event Action = open` but the Campaigns are not showing up.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the same situation. If we set the URL begin with "HTTP", everything is OK. But if we use "HTTPS", no campaign data shows up. Maybe it's a solution for you.